# xapth - get distinct nodes by attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have following xml:

```
<RD>
    <C id="1" pna="00-002" value="value1" />
    <C id="7" pna="00-008" value="value2"/>
    <C id="8" pna="00-009" value="value3"/>
    <C id="9" pna="00-009" value="value4"/>
    <C id="10" pna="00-010" value="value5"/>
    <C id="26" pna="00-025" value="value6"/>
    <C id="27" pna="00-026" value="value7"/>
    <C id="28" pna="00-026" value="value8"/>
    <C id="29" pna="00-026" value="value9"/>
    <C id="30" pna="00-026" value="value10"/>
    <C id="31" pna="00-027" value="value11"/>
</RD>
```

I want to get only distinct nodes by attribute pna. Example result:

```
<C id="1" pna="00-002" value="value1" />
<C id="7" pna="00-008" value="value2"/>
<C id="8" pna="00-009" value="value3"/>
<C id="10" pna="00-010" value="value5"/>
<C id="26" pna="00-025" value="value6"/>
<C id="27" pna="00-026" value="value7"/>
<C id="31" pna="00-027" value="value11"/>
```

I can use this xpath to get distinct values:
distinct-values(/RD/C/@pna)
, but I want to get nodes, not values.

Scenario:

1. get distinct values by attribute pna (eg: using distinct-values())
2. loop through distinct values list and find in xml node (first or last node, not matter), that pna attribute has the same value as iterator

Note that I can’t use following-sibling or preceding-sibling functions, because the same value of attribute pna may occur more than 2 times.
Is it possible to do this in pure xpath, without use any programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath would be `/RD/C[not(./@pna = following::C/@pna)]`.

See test [here](http://xpather.com/FWEXkgw6).

Answer (score 1):

The following XPath 1.0 expression should suit your needs :

```
//C[position()=1 or translate(@pna,"-","")>translate(preceding-sibling::C[1]/@pna,"-","")]
```

Output from your sample data : 7 nodes.

[image: XMLO]